# Hide price, "add to cart" button and show message "Please log in to shop"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My problem is simple, I just don't want user to shop unless and until user is not logged in. I also want to show specific message "Please Log In First" instead of price or add to cart button on the single product page.

I can hide price and add to cart functionality by using...

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        //Remove single product add to cart            
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);

        //Remove single product price
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);

        //Remove loop add to cart
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

        //Remove loop price
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
    }
```

How can I show message "Please log in first" on single product page instead of add to cart button?

Comment: This is clearly a 3rd party plugin issue and has nothing to do with WordPress core. Ask your question in [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [plugin's support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so easy. I was looking solution like this...

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wl8ShowCustomMsgToGuest', 10);

function wl8ShowCustomMsgToGuest(){
        //
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            $wc_ac_url = get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id'));
            $msg = __('Please log in to see the price.', 'wdmacspc');
            echo "<a href='$wc_ac_url' class='button alt wl8-custom-btn'>$msg</a>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put some conditionals where you render your button. You'll also need to figure out which page you're on.

```
if($is_single_product_page) {

    if( ! is_user_logged_in()) { ?>

        <div class="message">Please log in first</div>

    <?php } else { // end is_user_logged_in/false 
    ?>

        <button class="btn">add to cart</button>

    <?php } // end is_user_logged_in/true
}
```

Comment: The student has become the teacher

Answer (score 0):

I would do this first: 
In your site's admin go to WooCommerce>Settings>Checkout ex:
[image: WooCommerce require registration to buy]

Then I would add what @jgraup suggested.